# Rendering dynamic content on their own pages

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, wordpress-rest-api

Follow up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48459816/dynamic-routing-with-react-blog-posts-and-wordpress-api/48460099#48460099). I'm trying to work on generating completely separate views for data that's dynamically rendered from the WordPress API. I'm able to generate the the new link, but I keep getting undefined errors because the data isn't being properly passed. Where am I getting it wrong?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import Articles from './Articles';
import Article from './Article';

let article;
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="nav">
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <Link to="/category">Category</Link>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <Link to="/articles">Articles</Link>&nbsp;&nbsp;

        </div>

        <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path={"/"} component={Home} />
          <Route path={"/category"} component={Category} />
          <Route path={"/articles"} component={Articles} />
          <Route path="/news/:articleSlug" render={(props) => <Article  {...props} />} />

        </Switch>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Articles.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Article from './Article';

const newsURL = "http://myprivateblogapi.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed";

export default class Articles extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      newsData: [],
      requestFailed: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(newsURL)
      .then(response => {
        if(!response.ok) {
          throw Error("Network request failed.");
        }
        return response
      })
      .then(d => d.json())
      .then(d => {
        this.setState({
          newsData: d
        })
      }, () => {
        this.setState({
          requestFailed: true
        })
      })
  }

  render() {

    let articles = this.state.newsData.map((article, index) => {
      if(this.state.requestFailed) return <p>Failed!</p>
      if(!this.state.newsData) return <p>Loading...</p> 
      return(
        <div key={index} className="article-container">

          <div className="article-preview">
          <span className="article-date">{article.date}</span>
          <h5>{article.title.rendered}</h5>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: article.excerpt.rendered }} />

          <Link to={`/news/${article.slug}`}>Read More...</Link>

          </div>
          <Route path={`/news/:articleSlug`}
            render={ props => <Article data={article} {...props} />} />
        </div>

      )
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>All Articles from Blog</h3>
        {articles}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Article.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Article = ({match, data}) => {
  let articleData;

  if(data)
    articleData = <div>
      <h3> {data.title.rendered}</h3>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.content.rendered }} />
      <hr />
    </div>

  else 
    articleData = <h2> Sorry. That article doesn't exist. </h2>;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {articleData}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}

export default Article;
```

The page keeps defaulting to the "Sorry" block.

Comment: **@ Articles.js** Are you sure you're returning a promise when calling `return response`? If not You need to call one of these promise based [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response).

Have you tried `return response.json()` then removing the duplicate thenable?

Comment: @TobiahRex I tried replacing the line with `return response.json()`, and i got rid of `.then(d => d.json())` but that didn't change anything...

Comment: Interesting.  What's going on with the 3rd thenable?  Looks like your inside some sort of anonymous function call where use setState to assign the requestFailed to true?  Is that some sort of callback as the 2nd argument?  Doesnt look right.  Some odd syntax.

Comment: I'm following a tutorial for the API calls here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjavMX8fUAE), but the anonymous function is supposed to handle the errors if any of the previous thenables fail

Comment: Ah - i see.  Well, in that case, it's definitely incorrect.  You handle promise based errors with `.catch` if you didn't already know.  Try this...

``js
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(newsURL)
      .then(response => {
        if(!response.ok) {
          throw Error("Network request failed.");
        }
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(d => {
        this.setState({
          newsData: d
        })
      }).catch(() => {
        this.setState({
          requestFailed: true
        })
      });
  }
``

Comment: BTW - If you're just starting out with React, i HIGHLY suggest you use linting.  You can search for __eslint react setup__ if you need help.  I also have a setup [here](https://github.com/TobiahRex/coin-hundred/blob/master/package.json#L50) (npm packages) & [here](https://github.com/TobiahRex/coin-hundred/blob/master/.eslintrc) (.eslintrc setup) if you need a reference.  It'll catch syntax errors like that as they appear.  Necessary tool while just starting out  IMHO.

Comment: @TobiahRex thanks for the heads up. I'll check out the linting going forward. I've also changed the componentDidMount() method, but I'm still getting errors that articleData in the `Article` component is undefined. I'm guessing the issue is how the data is being passed...